# jQuery display fadeout element again

Tags: jquery, html

When the Ajax call on the page finishes, I am calling the below line of code to hide the processing message.

```
j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeOut();
```

But when the user initiates the same Ajax call again, I am trying to display the processing message as below but it does not display.

```
document.getElementById('deleteActionStatusId').innerHTML = "Processing...";
```

The developer console shows that `deleteActionStatusId` has its style property set to `display : none` because of the jQuery `fadeOut` call. How do I reverse this process, so that it works for the next Ajax call also?

Comment: You would have to call `j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeIn();` or `j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').show();`

Comment: Did you try using fadeIn() for the next Ajax call?

Comment: This comment is for the user who downvoted: If this question is so simple and stupid for you then why you never upvoted my other tough question on Jquery validator(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681421/jquery-validator-not-firing). I know that fadeIn is opposite of fadeIn but I did not want animation affect when showing the element again. It was my fault and ignorance that I did not know about show method. Easy questions should not be upvoted but at the same time should not be downvoted as per this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265565/downvoting-stupid-simple-questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kek06xu3/ (refresh the page to try the other one)

```
$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeIn();
```

or use:

```
$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').show();
```

If you wish to fade it in again, use `fadeIn()`. If you just want it to show (like it pops out), you should use `show()`. Also, mixing up Javascript and jQuery will look weird and you should avoid it. You should change your whole code to:

```
//Fade the element out
$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeOut();

//Select the element with id = deleteActionStatusId and change it to processing
$('#deleteActionStatusId').html("Processing");

//Make it show the element again
$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeIn();
```

Instead of doing `document.getElementById('deleteActionStatusId')` you can just do `$('#deleteActionStatusId')` and it will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is call the `fadeIn()` method, like this:

```
j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeIn();
```

[jQuery fadeIn method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Answer (score 0):

Following line will not remove `display:none` set by `.fadeOut()` event.

```
document.getElementById('deleteActionStatusId').innerHTML = "Processing...";
```

You can use one of the following technique to display your content again.

```
j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').css({display: "block"});
j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').fadeIn();
j$('[id$="deleteActionStatusId"]').show();
```